# lost my entire transfer

Tags: transactions, coinbase.com

ok, I had put all my investments into USD wallet on Binance, then I went to coinbase.com under account tools hit the drop box for addresses took the USD address there and copied it.

I returned to Binance and scheduled the transfer. it left Binance and within an hour it came as pending on coinbase.com, where it remained 7 days.

here's the hitch. I transferred 464.00 and some change. after 7 days it shows as 6 cents in my coinbase BTC wallet.

the irony is you can't even transfer 6 cents ..and I have emailed both parties and keep getting stupid replies that are no place near what I'm asking them.

and no phone numbers to call a real person. where my money? can I get it back?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Since you say, "it left binance and within a hour it came as pending on coinbase where it remained 7 days..." - do you have a transaction ID? It is possible to lookup a transaction to see what has happened with that, or with a sending or receiving address the transaction can probably be found indirectly? You can edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I can give you just one advise. Never use coinbase.com. they don't provide real Bitcoin wallet.

Comment: I have the transaction is how do I do that. new to this entire thing sorry

Comment: I have txid and address. but how do I trace it? when it opens on binance it is correct. on coinbase (recieving end)it is not correct.. at a complete loss.

Comment: @MischelleDanaHomawoo You can see what has happened using the txid's and addresses on [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info/). Just search for the txid it will show up.

Answer (score 2):

don't know if this help 
but I had the same problem 
COINBASE FIX IT 
sent btc to my coinbase receive address but I did not cover the fee>> fee amount to low .
2 1/2 week went by it showed pending on coinbase 
blockchain showed no transaction completed.

it first show back in my personal wallet 
then a week later coinbase shows I received btc 0.000685 btc

> > I sent 0.3555000
> >     but 1 week later it pulls from my wallet and goes to coinbase in full.
> >     so coinbase did something on there end to push it through.
> >     I was out nothing . 
> >     but it takes 3 to 4 weeks for them to fix it .
> >     hope it help you

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Thank you for posting a useful answer.